# UITableview cell with alternating background image

Tags: uitableview

I have a problem using the following code to set background of UITAbleview. 
Can I have a alternative images on the cell inside the UITable by using the following code?

e.g. cell 1 using X.png and cell 2 using Y.png?

tableView.opaque = NO;
  [tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wood.png"]]];
 cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lightwood.jpg"]];

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Specify what do you want?I am not clear about your question.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, what i am trying to do is to have a table, inside each cell row can they have different background image? e.g. the first row item is using X.png image then the second row uses Y.png image. Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first take a view in your .h file `UIView *newView;`  declare its property and synhesize it at your .m file

Now in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
if(cell==nil){
................
.........
newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:newView];
................
...............
}
if(indexPath.row == 0){

    newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lightwood.jpg"]];

}
if(indexPath.row == 1){

    newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lightwood.jpg"]];

}
if(indexPath.row == 2){

    newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lightwood.jpg"]];

}
```

If any further question please knock me.

EDIT:

if any problem still now then check this link http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html